# Generate all possible dataframes by combining rows of a initial dataframe

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:

```
> prueba
        S1 S2  S3 M1 M2  M3
Block-1 23 67 143 37 87 104
Block-2 43 76 145 43 76 103
Block-3 35 87 165 44 88 116
Block-4 45 55 145 43 97 156
Block-5 33 65 159 54 96 145
Block-6 37 54 139 51 91 166
Block-7 33 56 149 56 93 156
Block-8 38 55 135 57 94 167
Block-9 33 52 134 59 98 168
```

So, I want to generate all possible diferent dataframes by combining only 6 of the 9 rows that have the initial dataframe. Thanks to the "combn" function, I know there are 84 combinations of 6 blocks, now I want to have in a list of dataframes all those combinations with their respective S1,S2,S3,M1,M2,M3 values.

The solution would be like this:

```
> prueba1
        S1 S2  S3 M1 M2  M3
Block-1 23 67 143 37 87 104
Block-2 43 76 145 43 76 103
Block-3 35 87 165 44 88 116
Block-4 45 55 145 43 97 156
Block-5 33 65 159 54 96 145
Block-6 37 54 139 51 91 166

> prueba2
        S1 S2  S3 M1 M2  M3
Block-1 23 67 143 37 87 104
Block-2 43 76 145 43 76 103
Block-3 35 87 165 44 88 116
Block-4 45 55 145 43 97 156
Block-5 33 65 159 54 96 145
Block-7 33 56 149 56 93 156
```

·
·
·

Thanks.

Comment: You could make a nice list of data.frames with `lapply(combn(nrow(prueba), 6, simplify = FALSE), function(i){prueba[i, ]})`, but you might look into methods of cross validation that don't require storing repeated data, like `modelr::resample`.

Comment: Are you looking for `apply(combn(nrow(prueba), ncol(prueba)), 2, function(x) prueba[x,])`?